# Efficient way to add rows to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28056171/how-to-build-and-fill-pandas-dataframe-from-for-loop) and others it seems that it is not recommended to use `concat` or `append` to build a pandas dataframe because it is recopying the whole dataframe each time.

My project involves retrieving a small amount of data every 30 seconds. This might run for a 3 day weekend, so someone could easily expect over 8000 rows to be created one row at a time. What would be the most efficient way to add rows to this dataframe?

Comment: If you are only adding a row every 30 seconds, does it really need to be efficient?

Comment: Is there any reason it needs to be a DataFrame? Why not just write it to a file and then convert at the end?

Comment: @Stephen Rauch Well, I was hoping to keep my samples as close to every 30 seconds as possible. Probably incorrectly, I am pulling the data then adding it to the dataframe then using `time.sleep(30)` until its time to get the next set of data. My worry was that it becomes larger that the load time will start to expand the time between each sample. From this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715965/add-one-row-in-a-pandas-dataframe) it seems that at a size of 6000 it takes 2.29 seconds. I would like if possible to keep that number to a minimum.

Comment: If your concern is that the 30 second sleep will be inaccurate because it takes longer to append your data, then fix the sleep. `next_time += 30, time.sleep(next_time-time.time())`

Comment: @Stephen Rauch Oh that's a great idea!

Comment: OK Good, now that we have the timing out of the way, go with the spirit of @burhankhalid answer below, and put your data on disk (or in a DB) to be processed later.  Way more reliable for any long term data acquisition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [add one row in a pandas.DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715965/add-one-row-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Editing the chosen answer here since it was completely mistaken. What follows is an explanation of why you *should not* use setting with enlargement.  **"Setting with enlargement" is actually worse than append.**

The **tl;dr** here is that **there is no efficient way to do this with a DataFrame, so if you need speed you should use another data structure instead.** See other answers for better solutions.

### More on setting with enlargement

You can add rows to a DataFrame in-place using `loc` on a non-existent index, but that also performs a copy of all of the data (see [this discussion](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/10692)). Here's how it would look, from the [Pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#setting-with-enlargement):

```
In [119]: dfi
Out[119]: 
   A  B  C
0  0  1  0
1  2  3  2
2  4  5  4

In [120]: dfi.loc[3] = 5

In [121]: dfi
Out[121]: 
   A  B  C
0  0  1  0
1  2  3  2
2  4  5  4
3  5  5  5
```

For something like the use case described, **setting with enlargement actually takes 50% longer than `append`**:

With `append()`, 8000 rows took 6.59s (0.8ms per row)

```
%%timeit df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["A", "B", "C"]); new_row = pd.Series({"A": 4, "B": 4, "C": 4})
for i in range(8000):
    df = df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)

# 6.59 s ± 53.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

With `.loc()`, 8000 rows took 10s (1.25ms per row)

```
%%timeit df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["A", "B", "C"]); new_row = pd.Series({"A": 4, "B": 4, "C": 4})
for i in range(8000):
    df.loc[i] = new_row

# 10.2 s ± 148 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

### What about a longer DataFrame?

As with all profiling in data-oriented code, YMMV and you should test this for your use case. One characteristic of the copy-on-write behavior of `append` and "setting with enlargement" is that it will get slower and slower with large `DataFrame`s:

```
%%timeit df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["A", "B", "C"]); new_row = pd.Series({"A": 4, "B": 4, "C": 4})
for i in range(16000):
    df.loc[i] = new_row

# 23.7 s ± 286 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Building a 16k row `DataFrame` with this method takes 2.3x longer than 8k rows.

Comment: Thank you, this looks to be much better than what I was using. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Anything less hackish than assuming some index will never exist?

Comment: Of course the latter is faster. The first iteration adds a new row, and all subsequent operations write to the same row with index 3. The index has to be incremented. You'd also need df = df.append(df2) to make the comparison fair.

Comment: Also it could be a good idea to test a reindexation with the new rows (with pandas.reindex) and then copy the new data with np.array.

Comment: @waterproof: please do not edit answers. It an answer is wrong, just add an answer. You should never change the meaning of an answer with edit.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi good point, this edit was probably over the top. I was so young back then xD. Don't worry, my more recent edits are generally limited to formatting, clarification, updates to things that have become out of date, etc.

Answer (score 84):

I used this answer's `df.loc[i] = [new_data]` suggestion, but I have > 500,000 rows and that was very slow.

While the answers given are good for the OP's question, I found it more efficient, when dealing with large numbers of rows up front (instead of the trickling in described by the OP) to use csvwriter to add data to an in memory CSV object, then finally use `pandas.read_csv(csv)` to generate the desired DataFrame output.

```
from io import BytesIO
from csv import writer 
import pandas as pd

output = BytesIO()
csv_writer = writer(output)

for row in iterable_object:
    csv_writer.writerow(row)

output.seek(0) # we need to get back to the start of the BytesIO
df = pd.read_csv(output)
return df
```

This, for ~500,000 rows was 1000x faster and as the row count grows the speed improvement will only get larger (the `df.loc[1] = [data]` will get a lot slower comparatively)

Comment: Could one alternatively, efficiently use an in-memory structure or CSV instead of actually writing a CSV to file?

Comment: @matanster To my understanding, and that is what the author actually states himself as well, this is already in memory. So hard to beat it. Is this actually faster than appending to a list and converting that?

Comment: Great ! I tested and can confirm that this is much faster.

Comment: Note: for Python 3 need to [use StringIO instead of BytesIO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41291817)

Comment: I add a simpler solution below that use a dictionary, working very well for very large dataframe.

Comment: Wow, thank you SO much for this. Much easier and faster than what I was doing. It brought the computation time from ~2 hours to 2 minutes!

Comment: Why not just using ```output = []```, ```output.append(row)```, ```pd.DataFrame(output)```?

Comment: How would I indicate index?

Answer (score 10):

[Tom Harvey's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48287388) works well. However, I would like to add a simpler solution based on [pandas.DataFrame.from_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html).

By adding the data of a row in a list and then this list to a dictionary, you can then use `.from_dict(dict)` to create a dataframe without iteration.

If each value of the dictionary is a row, you can use just:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictionary, orient='index')
```

Small example:

```py
# Dictionary containing the data
dic = {
    'row_1': ['some', 'test', 'values', 78, 90],
    'row_2': ['some', 'test', 'values', 100, 589]}

# Creation of the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dic, orient='index')
df
```

```
          0     1       2    3    4
row_1  some  test  values   78   90
row_2  some  test  values  100  589
```

Comment: It is very fast even for large dictionary.

Comment: What do you mean by large? I need to find an alternative of enlarging/growing a pandas DataFrame with one million rows. Do you think this could be more efficient?

Comment: I use it for a dataframe of 12 million rows. And it works perfectly. Dictionaries are perfect for large dataset because when using a dictionary the average time complexity of adding or removing rows is O(1).

Answer (score 6):

You need to split the problem into two parts:

1. Accepting the data (collecting it) every 30 seconds efficiently.
2. Processing the data once its collected.

If your data is critical (that is, you cannot afford to lose it) - send it to a queue and then read it from the queue in batches.

The queue will provide reliable (guaranteed) acceptance and that your data will not be lost.

You can read the data from the queue and dump it in a database.

Now your Python app simply reads from the database and does the analysis at whatever interval makes sense for the application - perhaps you want to do hourly averages; in this case you would run your script each hour to pull the data from the db and perhaps write the results in another database / table / file.

The bottom line - split the collecting and analyzing parts of your application.

Comment: This is a great idea! Probably a bit outside of my skill level at the moment but this just gives me so many good ideas!!! I think after I get it up and running I will try and make something like this happen. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your dataframe is indexed in order you can:

First check to see what the next index value is to create a new row:

```
myindex = df.shape[0]+1
```

Then use 'at' to write to each desired column

```
df.at[myindex,'A']=val1
df.at[myindex,'B']=val2
df.at[myindex,'C']=val3
```

Answer (score 2):

[sundance's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41888241) might be correct in terms of usage, but the benchmark is just wrong.
As [correctly pointed out by moobie](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41888080/41888241#comment92755411_41888241), an index 3 already exists in this example, which makes access way quicker than with a non-existent index.  Have a look at this:

```
%%timeit
test = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3], "B": [1,2,3], "C": [1,2,3]})
for i in range(0,1000):
    testrow = pd.DataFrame([0,0,0])
    pd.concat([test[:1], testrow, test[1:]])
```

2.15 s ± 88 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

```
%%timeit
test = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3], "B": [1,2,3], "C": [1,2,3]})
for i in range(0,1000):
    test2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': 0, 'B': 0, 'C': 0}, index=[i+0.5])
    test.append(test2, ignore_index=False)
test.sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
```

972 ms ± 14.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

```
%%timeit
test = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3], "B": [1,2,3], "C": [1,2,3]})
for i in range(0,1000):
    test3 = [0,0,0]
    test.loc[i+0.5] = test3
test.reset_index(drop=True)
```

1.13 s ± 46 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Of course, this is purely synthetic, and I admittedly wasn't expecting these results, but it seems that with non-existent indices `.loc` and `.append` perform quite similarly. Just leaving this here.

Answer (score 2):

I had 700K rows of data returned from SQL server.
All of the above took too long for me.
The following approach cut the time significantly.

```
from collections import defaultdict
dict1 = defaultdict(list)

for row in results:

   dict1['column_name1'] = row['column_name1']


   dict1['column_name20'] = row['column_name20']

df = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
```

This is all I needed.

Answer (score 0):

My coworker told me to make a list of dictionary entries, then push the finished list into a dataframe.  Compared to pushing one dictionary at a time into a dataframe, the list approach was instantaneous.

This code culled through ~54k records and looks only for those after my targ_datetime value, then writes the desired value back to a list, and then to df_out:

```
df_out = pd.DataFrame()
df_len = df.count()
counter = 1
list_out = []
targ_datetime = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat('2021-12-30 00:00:00')
for rec in df.selectExpr("CAST(data as STRING) as data").take(df_len):
  j = jsonx.loads(rec[0])
  NewImage = j['dynamodb']['NewImage']
  NewImage['eventName'] = j['eventName']
  if j.get('dynamodb').get('NewImage').get('UPDATED_AT') != None:
    ts = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(str(j['dynamodb']['NewImage']['UPDATED_AT']).replace('T', ' ')[0:-5])
  else:
    ts = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(j['dynamodb']['ApproximateCreationDateTime']/1000)
  if ts >= targ_datetime:
    #df_out = df_out.append(pd.Series(NewImage.values(), index=NewImage.keys()), ignore_index=True)
    j['dynamodb']['NewImage']['UPDATED_AT'] = ts
    list_out.append(NewImage)
    counter = counter +1
  #if counter > 10: break
df_out = pd.DataFrame(list_out)
```