# Append DataFrame Rows In-Place Within a Function in Pandas: Elegant Solutions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pass-by-reference, reassign

I am looking for a clear and efficient way to append rows to a DataFrame in-place within a function in pandas. Here's what I got so far:

1. `pd.concat` Approach (Not In-Place):

   ```
   def append_rows_concat(df, new_rows):
       return pd.concat([df, new_rows], ignore_index=True)
   ```

   - iirc this creates a copy of the DataFrame, requiring reassignment. Not truly in-place/by-reference.
2. `.loc` Approach (In-Place, but Clunky):

   ```
   def append_rows_loc(df, new_rows):
       start_index = len(df)
       for i, row in new_rows.iterrows():
           df.loc[start_index + i] = row
   ```

   - Modifies DataFrame directly (in-place/by-reference), avoids copies
   - Less readable, maybe less efficient for large DFs due to row-by-row iteration

### Question

As per test code below, both options work as expected. Is there an elegant and reliable approach (like 1.), that is efficient, and true in-place modification (like 2.)? Aiming for direct modification and avoiding copies as with `pd.concat`, mostly to learn how it's done. Specifically, I want to keep various functions consistent in that that they modify the main df by-reference.

How to append efficiently has been discussed before [e.g. here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41888080/efficient-way-to-add-rows-to-dataframe), however, `pd.append` has been discontinued, and I really want to understand how to do this without re-assignment, even practically the df could be easily copied.

The question is how to do it inside a function (and by-reference, without reassignment of df via `return df`), not so much how it would be done in main.

python version: 3.11.7

pandas version: 2.1.4

### Test code

#### Setup

```
import pandas as pd

# some sample DFs
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': [1, 2, 3],
    'col2': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    'col3': [4, 5, 6]})
df_update = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': [11, 22],
    'col2': ['aa', 'bb']})
print(df)
print(df_update)
```

```
   col1 col2  col3
0     1    a     4
1     2    b     5
2     3    c     6
   col1 col2
0    11   aa
1    22   bb
```

#### `pd.concat` Approach

```
print(append_rows_concat(df, df_update))
print(df)
```

```
   col1 col2  col3
0     1    a   4.0
1     2    b   5.0
2     3    c   6.0
3    11   aa   NaN
4    22   bb   NaN
   col1 col2  col3
0     1    a     4
1     2    b     5
2     3    c     6
```

#### `.loc` Approach

```
append_rows_loc(df, df_update)  # Modifies df in place
print(df)
```

```
   col1 col2  col3
0     1    a   4.0
1     2    b   5.0
2     3    c   6.0
3    11   aa   NaN
4    22   bb   NaN
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficient way to add rows to dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41888080/efficient-way-to-add-rows-to-dataframe)
TLDR: There is no efficient way to add (many) rows to a pandas dataframe in-place. If this is required one should use a different data structure.

Comment: what's the use case? it really depends on the underlying data, what the keys, how are you adding new rows?

Comment: Unfortunately that post doesn't go into the by-reference VS by-reassignment question I am scratching my head about. Also `pd.append` has been deprecated since version 1.4.0 according to [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.4/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html)

Comment: The marked answer for that post discusses the use of loc for setting with enlargement. That is what you want to do. The anwser explains that this does not scale and that there is no efficient way to do what you want to do with panda dataframes. loc() is the only way to modify a dataframe in place and it is not efficient to use for many rows.

Comment: Yes agree that it looks that way... so .loc is really the only way? Is that the answer then?

Comment: concat, join, and merge, all of them create a copy due to the memory allocation mechanism of Python, you cannot change the size of the data structure and do an in-place operation at the same time!
therefore the .loc is your only option, and to optimize the process a bit, have a look at optimizing the data types and use chunks of your dataframe.